# Uploading a dataset from google drive to google colab

Tags: python, pandas, image

I am very new to data analytics/machine learning. I have been having trouble accessing my files from google drive to google colab. I have tried to find every way in the internet, however it still fails me.

So I have downloaded the dataset online. In this dataset, by the name of
'shopee-product-detection-dataset.zip'

In my first step of code, I did this,

```
   from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I understand, this would allow google colab to access my google drive.

My second step, I did

```
!unzip "./gdrive/My Drive/shopee-product-detection-dataset.zip"
```

I put my dataset right in my google drive, but when I run this code it gives me the error: unable to find shopee-product-detection-dataset.zip

Can someone help me out with this? Am I doing what normally people do putting their dataset in the google colab?

In this zip file, there is a train and test file which contains around 100k amounts of images, would you be able to recommend me any website/articles/video on which I can learn? Such as Tensorflow for begineers etc. I understand that we need to use the data to train which I would need to build a model from. But I am very new to this, and I would like to learn. I have watched some videos on youtube, however none of them have shown/taught me on how to use/import 100k images in the dataset for a machine learning model.

You comment is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29482/35644 Also please attach your code rather than in image

Comment: I think you should provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the steps you followed to advise/suggest you better.

Put the steps if you require.

1. Mount the gdrive:

   ```
   from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```

   Takes you to authenticate the gmail account and get pass phrase.
2. Locate the path in the drive:

   ```
   project_path = <<File containing path in the gdrive >> os.chdir(project_path)
   ```

Comment: Hi there! I have edited the post! I hope I am more clear with what I am trying to say. Thank you so much!